# Setup the Auto Timestamp in PhpMyAdmin

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, installation, timestamp

Would anyone show me how the step by step setting up the Timestamp here in PhpMyAdmin? I think I have a wrong setup. Please see the screenshot I attached.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot1]

Comment: while design table there are choice of data types, where date, date time, time stamp are available

Comment: hello @user1844933 thank you for your time but I don't get what's your point?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add TIMESTAMP data type with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP like below:

```
CREATE TABLE `timestamp` (
    id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    `date` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
)
```

`id` and `name` I have inserted for your understanding.

You can also simply select from the data type drop down while creating the table as shown below:
[image]

Now next time when you insert any data from PHP to your table, current timestamp will automatically inserted in column like shown below:

Adding DATA from PHP (Adding from MySql now for understanding)
[image]

After Adding data, you can see timestamp automatically generated in table like below:

[image]

Hope it will clear out your problem.

Comment: thank you @Amit really appreciated ^___^. Blessed you

Comment: @AmitGupta, I tried this step. I am getting this issue on time. Time is not showing IST. I know I have to change the timezone but where I have go and change it.

Comment: You can change the timezone like:- date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");

Answer (score 0):

step 1 -> click the "Structure" in your first screenshot
step 2 -> [image: Click this image to see]

step 3 -> now choose `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` on attributes